# Select rows in order of total count

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have a table of users which hold a a users id that they voted for like this:

```
uid | voted_for
 1  |   3
 2  |   3
 3  |   1
```

What i'm aiming to do is order uid based on how many people have voted for that uid. But I have no idea how to do it.

So the end result would be:

```
uid | Total_Votes
 3  |     2
 1  |     1
 2  |     0
```

Hope you can help explain the best way to structure the SQL for this.

Comment: Can there be more than one row with the same uid - ie myiple voted_for values for a given uid?

Comment: one user can vote for only one person. so `uid` is unique.

Comment: Then how does total_votes differe from votes_for? Is there another column in your table you're not showing us, like uid_voted_for?

Comment: @Bohemian See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/946f9/2

Comment: I don't understand why you need a group at all. Is the resulting rows you want the same numbers of rows in the users table but in a different order?

Comment: You group because there could be more than one person that has voted for a given person.

Comment: I finally get it! See my answer for a *much* simpler query than the other answer (which is way over-complicated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple query will produce the output you requested:

```
select voted_for as uid, count(*) as total_votes
from users
group by 1
order by 2 desc
```

---

If you want all data about each user in the output, join users to itself:

```
select u.*, count(v.uid) as total_votes
from users u
left join users v on v.voted_for = u.uid
group by 1,2,3,4,5 -- put as many numbers here as there are columns in the users table
order by total_votes desc
```

This second query will give a `total_votes` score of zero if no one voted for the user.

Alternatively, you can select only those columns you want:

```
select u.uid, u.name, count(v.uid) as total_votes
from users u
left join users v on v.voted_for = u.uid
group by 1,2
order by 3 desc
```

```

To return only the winners, do this:

```
select u.uid, u.name, count(*) as total_votes
from users u
left join users v on v.voted_for = u.uid
group by 1,2
having count(*) = (
    select max(c) from (
        select count(*) as c from users group by voted_for))
order by 3 desc
```

Comment: Ah see i tried your first method and had only users which had 1 or more votes. I'm a little confused by the `group by 1,2,3,4,5` not seen that before - can you explain it ?

Comment: you must mention all non-aggregates columns in the `group by` clause. You may refer to them by name/expression *or* by column position. Let's say users table (not shown) has these columns: `uid, name, joined_date, age, voted_for` then `group by 1,2,3,4,5` is equivalent to `group by uid, name, joined_date, age, voted_for`. Code the group by how you want, just make sure if you select `u.*` that you mention *all* columns from `users` in the group by clause (or the query won't work properly, even though it won't error either)

Comment: Ah so even fields not used in my `select` have to still be included for the `group by` - shame there is no simple `ALL` to represent that xD

Comment: I agree it is a shame you can't just say "all", but that's the way it is. You don't have to select `u.*` - you could select just those columns you want. I'll add an example to the answer

Comment: By the way for some reason i get `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1056 Can't group on 'total_votes'` which is not making sense as my SQL group section is `GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6`

Comment: Group by the column position, or see alternative answer. Look - how many columns are in users?

Comment: I have - i believe your solution is more simplified and elegant which will benefit future onlookers. I have it working now thank you :)

Comment: As a side note, you wouldn't happen to know a clever to count how many rows have equal `most votes` encase for example more than one person are joint first. As i will need to do such a check in a seperate query.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30722/discussion-between-bohemian-and-dave)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this will help joining the table on itself:

```
SELECT u.*, voted_for_cnt
FROM users u
   LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT voted_for, count(1) voted_for_cnt 
      FROM users
      GROUP BY voted_for
   ) t ON u.uid = t.voted_for
ORDER BY t.voted_for_cnt DESC
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/946f9/2)

Comment: Awesome thank you! And thanks for introducing me to SQL fiddle :D

Comment: @Dave -- np, glad I could help!